# Calling a Method within itself in c#

Tags: c#, monogame

I have looked into other similar posts and was unable to find exactly what i needed from them so sorry if you have seen a similar post.

Im working on a monogame GameObject class, and was implementing a system to parent and child GameObjects, however the current design only iterates through one level of the hierarchy, for instance if the Parent was I, its child J would move with it, however J's child Q doesn't move.

To fix this i was wondering if it would be possible to call the same method within itself

Here is the sample code for moving parent/child objects

```
        public void Transform(Vector2 newPosition)
        {  
            if (children.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (GameObject i in children)
                {
                    Vector2 diff = new Vector2(-(position.X - newPosition.X), -(position.Y - newPosition.Y));
                    i.position = i.position + diff;
                    i.Transform(new Vector2(i.position.X, i.position.Y));
                }
            }
            position.X = newPosition.X;
            position.Y = newPosition.Y;
        }
```

As you can see im trying to run the method within itself, however, when the program is run, every child below the first parent doesnt move.

Thanks for any help

Comment: when you call `Transform` inside loop, this will update `children` and ``position`` objects,  not children of `children`. can you add `Children` collection `position` object to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a standard computer science technique called *recursion*

Edit: I was going to add some more details and got pulled away.

```
Recursion is often used to walk graph data structures, especially trees, but its a general technique.  In pesudo-code recursive logic looks like this

RecursiveFunction(someProblem)
   IF  someProblem has a trivial solution THEN
       RETURN the trivial solution
   ELSE
       Reduce Some Problem to make it simpler
       ADD RecursiveFunction(SomeProblem) to our local solution
       RETURN the local solution
```

A simple example would be a binary tree walk which would look like this

```
BinaryTreePrinter(treeNode,indentLevel)
   PRINT(INDENT(indentLevel)+treeNode.name)
   IF (treeNode.Left not null) THEN
      BinaryTreePrinter(treeNode.Left,indentLevel+1)
   ENDIF
   IF (treenode.Right not null) THEN
      BinaryTreePrinter(treeNode.Right,indentLevel+1)
   ENDIF
```

The one thing to be wary of in recursion is that every call takes up a new frame on the stack.  If you have a bug or your recursion is simply too deep, you can run out of stack space. As an example, this will loop unti yo urun otu of stack and the program crashes. (Modern managed languages will throw an exception)

```
BadRecursion(foo)
   BadRecursion(foo)
```

Comment: I believe, that OP is asking about C#

Comment: Yes but his question is broader and it is important for him to learn that recursion is an important general principle that applies to ALL stack based procedural languages.  That is the difference between being a "coder" and being a software engineer.

Teach a man to fish and he will eat for life as  long as there is a river.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is already calling itself from within itself.

[image]

It looks like your code is getting mixed up between vectors and positions to me. You could try and simplify you code like this:

```
    public void Transform(Vector2 arg)
    {
        foreach (GameObject child in children)
        {
            child.Transform(arg);
        }

        position.X += arg.X;
        position.Y += arg.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. This type of solution is called recursion. Bear in mind that you must provide an exit condition or you will fill the stack with function calls and get a stack overflow exception. The recursive loop doesn't have to be infinite to cause this problem either; you will also get this exception if you exceed the stack size limit by doing it too many times.

Here is an example of C# being used in such a way to calculate the nth value of the Fibonacci sequence using recursion. Found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/function/csharp-function-exercise-12.php).

```
using System;
public class funcexer12
{
 public static int Fib(int n1)
 {
  //if ( (n1 == 1) || (number == 2) )
    if (n1 <=2)
      return 1;
      else
      return Fib( n1 - 1 ) + Fib( n1 - 2 );
 }

 public static void Main()
 {
      int num;

      Console.Write("\n\nRecursive Function : To calculate the Fibonacci number of a specific term :\n");
      Console.Write("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");   
      Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
      num = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );

      Console.WriteLine("\nThe Fibonacci of {0} th term  is {1} \n", num, Fib(num));
 }
}
```

On the topic of parent/child structures, recursion is commonly used in tree structures.I use it in a Unity game of mine to traverse the outputs of trees of logic gates. I have no experience with monogame so I can't be any more specific about your problem other than to tell you that functions calling themselves is possible and can be useful.